# I am fairly new to Java Inheritance and I don't understand why I have an error?

Tags: java, inheritance

Here is the problem:

**Write the class Marketer to accompany the other law firm classes described in this chapter. Marketers make $50,000 ($10,000 more than general employees) and have an additional method called advertise that prints "Act now, while supplies last!" Make sure to interact with the Employee superclass as appropriate.**

The code so far:

```
public class Marketer extends Employee {   

public Marketer() { 
        setBaseSalary(super.getSalary() + 10000.0);    
    }

    public void advertise() {
        System.out.println("Act now, while supplies last!") ;
    }
}
```

This is what the output should be:

*50000.0*

*75535.0*

*Act now, while supplies last!*

There is a file extension called **Employee.java** on the following site that the code above follows:
http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?id=1324

So what I have so far, it printed out every expected outcome ***EXCEPT for 75535.0***!
Where did I go wrong??
When I ran the code, it said this (for the error I had received on the 75535.0 part):

*(change base salary to $65535.00)*

because my output was 65535.0, which is 10000 less than what the answer is supposed to be.

I can't seem to find the error since I just started to do these inheritance kind of things in Java, so I am still unfamiliar with it. Thank you if you can help me understand where I messed up.

Comment: Can you explain why 75535.0 is expected?  I don't see any numbers in the problem or Employee.java that would result in printing 75535.0.

Comment: What's in main method,how is above outputed

Comment: @Steven Hood I'm not sure...I know the default wage is $40,000 in the Employee.java. When I ran the code, it said this: "change base salary to $65535.00" for the 75535.0 expected output.

Comment: @Spring.Rush Employee.java is a class, so I don't think there's a main method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

Create Marketer, which calls Employee's constructor and instance initialization.  That sets `baseSalary` to 40,000.  Your code in the Markerter constructor then runs and sets `baseSalary` to 50,000.  Their test driver calls `setBaseSalary` with a value of 65535.0, overwriting your initial set.

Your code isn't properly interacting with the Employee class.  The comment in `Employee.java` says your code isn't supposed to use, call, or modify the values below.  One of those is the `baseSalary` variable, and you are modifying it in the `Marketer` constructor.  Once the test driver changes the value, your class has no way to compute the changed salary for the `Marketer`.

You shouldn't call `setBaseSalary` in your constructor.  Instead, override `getSalary` in Marketer, and use the `getSalary` method from Employee in your own class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution example:

```
    public class Marketer extends Employee {
        public void advertise() {
            System.out.println("Act now, while supplies last!");
        }
        public double getSalary() {
            return super.getSalary() + 10000;
        }
    }
```

It should help you understand problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem is simple. Just define Marketer class as below

```
public class Marketer extends Employee {   

    public void advertise() {
        System.out.println("Act now, while supplies last!") ;
    }

    @Override
    public double getSalary() {
        return super.getSalary() + 10000.0;               // $40,000.00
    } 
}
```

Here we override getSalary method of Employee class and whenever we have to return salary we add 10000 to the employee salary.

Hope this helps

Comment: my pleasure :)
please feel free to contact if any other help is required